# How to use restore_attributes in a Rails controller with nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, activemodel

Example: 
a `Person` model `accepts_nested_attributes_for` a `Pets` model as in the example found [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). Submitting a `form_for(@person)` with a nested `fields_for :pets` hits the update method in the PeoplesController. If there was an unsuccessful save i.e due to the pet's name failing a `presence: true` validation, how can one restore the changes made to the pet instance using ActiveModel::Dirty, therefore restoring the changes made
in the form? I want to do this so that the nested form inputs will retain the pet's values they had pre-save and not be blank.

Example:

```
def update
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.update_attributes(person_params)
      format.html { redirect_to persons_path }
    else
      # @person.restore_attributes works for restoring the @person 
      # input values. I would like to do something like 
      # @person.pet.restore_attributes
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to get this done. When using a nested fields_for, you have access to the object within that form, therefore you can call restore_attributes, etc. on it.

A rough example :

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :pets do |ff| %>
    <%  
    if ff.object.errors
      ff.object.restore_attributes
    end 
    %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```